# X.509 certificate cannot be found by WCF service

Tags: wcf, security, iis, x509certificate

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS.

Using `certmgr.msc` I can see my X.509 certificate in `Personal -> Certificates` but still I get this error:

Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria: StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'CurrentUser', FindType 'FindByThumbprint', FindValue 'b0 5f 3f ...'.

I changed storelocation, find type... but still the same error appears. I guess IIS cannot use the certificate because of lack of permission.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the cert, select Manage Private Keys, grant rights to the user under which the IIS app pool is running.

Comment: There's no `Manage Private Keys` option inside `certmgr.msc`. Where should I check ?

Comment: You have to click on the specific certificate to modify. The Manage Private Keys is under "All Tasks". Does the icon for the cert have a little key showing in the upper left corner of it? If not, there is no private key in the cert.